# How to get all imports defined in a class using java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, dependencies

Hi i am new in java reflection domain.So can anyone guide me in this problem scenario.

I have a **class** named **"SomClass.java"** and it **imports a package** named **"SomPackage.RefClass"**  And some other java libraries like java.lang.. etc.

**Now i wish to get know all the imports defined in a class through reflection.**

```
import SomPackage.RefClass;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.io.IOException; 
 public class SomeClass{
  RefClass refClass_Obj;
  String nationality;
///some other members
}
```

***I just wanna know the list of all import defined in a class using reflection.***

*I have seen a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884221/java-reflecting-on-method-scope-variables) posted hear similar to my Q but it is not well elaborated so,need some good direction of help.*

thanks in advance.

Comment: See here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928121/get-list-of-necessary-classes-for-a-class-to-load) for an answer which doesn't use reflection, or source code parsing, but bytecode reading instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I just wanna know the list of all
>   import defined in a class using
>   reflection

You can't because the compiler doesn't put them into the object file. It throws them away. Import is just a shorthand to the compiler.

Comment: As u explain "You can't because the compiler doesn't put them into the object file." I have try this and when i decompile a java file using some java Decompiler like DJ Java Decompiler.it will show all the imports(java libraries & as well packages).Can u explain this more?

Comment: @zaree No it won't. It will synthesize import statements for all the classes from other packages used by this class. It is not recreating the original source code.

Answer (score 16):

Imports are a compile-time feature - there's no difference to the compiled code between a version which uses the full name of the type everywhere it's mentioned, a version which imports everything using a *, and a version which imports classes by full name.

If you want to find all the types *used* within the compiled code, that's a slightly different matter. You may want to look at [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) as a way of analyzing bytecode.

Comment: @zaree - for completeness, there is no way to determine the types used within a type using the reflection APIs.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use [Qdox](https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox) to get all the imports in a class which is not actually through reflection, but it can serve your purpose :

```
    String fileFullPath = "Your\\java\\ file \\full\\path";
    JavaDocBuilder builder = new JavaDocBuilder();
    builder.addSource(new FileReader( fileFullPath  ));

    JavaSource src = builder.getSources()[0];
    String[] imports = src.getImports();

    for ( String imp : imports )
    {
        System.out.println(imp);
    }
```

Comment: No you can't. From your own link: 'QDox is a high speed, small footprint parser for extracting class/interface/method definitions from *source* files ...' [emphasis added]

Comment: Yes you are right, through reflection its not possible. But with Qdox its possible to get from .java file which might be useful for some others.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Asraful Haque qdox helps to read imports of java file

Use Maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.qdox</groupId>
            <artifactId>qdox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please refer modified version of code

```
package readimports;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaProjectBuilder;
import com.thoughtworks.qdox.model.JavaSource;

public class TestReadAllImport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileFullPath = "path to java file";
        JavaProjectBuilder builder = new JavaProjectBuilder();
        builder.addSource(new FileReader( fileFullPath  ));

        Collection<JavaSource> srcs = builder.getSources();
        for(JavaSource src : srcs) {
            List<String> imports = src.getImports();

            for ( String imp : imports )
            {
                System.out.println(imp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the qdox, I used it to recursively find all imports and find unique packages and unique imports.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.qdox/qdox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.qdox</groupId>
    <artifactId>qdox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Using simple recursion to get all packages and imports of the given class.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaProjectBuilder;
import com.thoughtworks.qdox.model.JavaSource;

public class ImportsIdentifier {

    private static String sysPath ="//<Absolute Path>/src/main/java/";
    private static String fileType = ".java";
    private static Set<String> importFiles = new HashSet<>();
    private static Set<String> packages = new HashSet<>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = sysPath + "<java file path>";
        
        printImports(path);
        
        System.out.println(importFiles);
        System.out.println(packages);
    }
    
    private static void printImports(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        JavaProjectBuilder jp = new JavaProjectBuilder();
        jp.addSource(new FileReader(path));

        Collection<JavaSource> srcs = jp.getSources();

        for (JavaSource src : srcs) {
            System.out.println(src.getPackage());
            packages.add(src.getPackage().toString());
            
            for(String imprt: src.getImports()) {
                if(imprt.startsWith("<filter for any package>")) {
                    
                    imprt = sysPath+imprt.replaceAll("\\.", "/")+fileType;
                    if(importFiles.contains(imprt)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    importFiles.add(imprt);
                    System.out.println(imprt);
                    
                    printImports(imprt);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```