# Java find out what imports a .class has

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bcel

Is there a way to find out what imports a class has?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701305/how-to-get-all-imports-defined-in-a-class-using-java-reflection) question: Jon Skeet says that you can't do this using reflection, but

> If you want to find all the types used within the compiled code,
>   that's a slightly different matter. You may want to look at BCEL as a
>   way of analyzing bytecode.

This is what I want to know how to do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701305/how-to-get-all-imports-defined-in-a-class-using-java-reflection

Comment: @nolegs I edited my question to reflect your comment

Comment: Do you mean in code (as in using reflection) or just from the class file (using a decompiler or similar?)

Comment: Classes are kept in the .class constant table, typed appropiately. There is one caveat: imported static final constants are copied, so that their class import might fall away. (At least that was so in sun's java.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734825/find-out-which-classes-of-a-given-api-are-used

Comment: As you already know you can't find the imports, why do your title and your first sentence ask it anyway? Please amended them to agree with what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an old tutorial for [ASM bytecode manipulation framework](http://asm.ow2.org) explaining [how to read class dependencies](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) with ASM.

Comment: Links don't work (which is why answers shouldn't be just links!). Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20151231173739/http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java Decompiler like this one:
[Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)